# How do we remove chessboard-like noise from an input image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm working on something which requires me to enhance an input image which has consistent chessboard-like noise all over it projected uniformly
[image: input image]

and this is the expected output image
[image: output image]

Comment: could you give an example? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I added the image to the original post

Comment: @AhmedElshamy do you have an example of what the expected output should be like too?

Comment: Are your images of constant size? Is the chessboard pattern of constant size/position? If so, you might consider just subtracting a pure chessboard pattern

Comment: @MLavrentyev the chessboard pattern and the image are both of const size yeah

Comment: Is the second image your input or the result of trying to clean it up?

Comment: Do notch filtering on the FFT.  If you do an FFT you will se a pattern of horizontal and vertical lines in the spectrum (log of the magnitude). From the spectrum, extract the lines (via hough line transform) and make a mask of the lines. Cover the center bright point in the mask with black to preserver the DC component. Apply the mask to the magnitude image and combine with the phase image and do IFFT.

Comment: @fmw42 the second image is the required output that I need to acquire

Comment: Post the input image or is the first image your input?

Comment: yes the first image is the input, the second is the expected output

Comment: The noise seems periodic. Try filtering in the frequency domain notching out the offending frequencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way using notch filtering in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input as grayscale
- Do DFT to complex real and imaginary components
- Shift the DC point to the center
- Convert the real and imaginary components to magnitude and phase
- Compute the spectrum image from the magnitude
- Threshold the spectrum image to extract the grid lines corresponding to the regular checkerboard pattern
- Blacken out the white region around the DC point in the center
- Invert the mask
- Multiply the magnitude by the mask
- Convert the new magnitude and old phase to real and imaginary components
- Combine real and imaginary components
- Shift the DC point to the top left corner
- Do the DIFT and convert to 8-bit range as the notched filter result
- Stretch the dynamic range to improve visibility
- Save results

Input:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import skimage.exposure

# read input as grayscale
# opencv fft only works on grayscale
img = cv2.imread('checkerboard_noise.jpg', 0)
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# convert image to floats and do dft saving as complex output
dft = cv2.dft(np.float32(img), flags = cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)

# apply shift of origin from upper left corner to center of image
dft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(dft)

# extract magnitude and phase images
mag, phase = cv2.cartToPolar(dft_shift[:,:,0], dft_shift[:,:,1])

# get spectrum for viewing only
spec = (np.log(mag) / 20)

# threshold spectrum as mask
mask = cv2.threshold(spec, 0.5, 1, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# blacken out center DC region from mask
cx = ww // 2
cy = hh // 2
mask = cv2.circle(mask, (cx,cy), 10, 0, -1)

# invert mask
mask = 1 - mask

# apply mask to magnitude image
mag_notch = mask*mag

# convert magnitude and phase into cartesian real and imaginary components
real, imag = cv2.polarToCart(mag_notch, phase)

# combine cartesian components into one complex image
complex = cv2.merge([real, imag])

# shift origin from center to upper left corner
complex_ishift = np.fft.ifftshift(complex)

# do idft with normalization saving as real output
img_notch = cv2.idft(complex_ishift, flags=cv2.DFT_SCALE+cv2.DFT_REAL_OUTPUT)
img_notch = img_notch.clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

# stretch contrast
img_notch_stretched = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(img_notch, in_range=(75,150), out_range=(0,255))

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("checkerboard_noise_spectrum.png", (255*spec).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8))
cv2.imwrite("checkerboard_noise_mask.png", (255*mask).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8))
cv2.imwrite("checkerboard_noise_notched.png", img_notch)
cv2.imwrite("checkerboard_noise_notched_stretched.png", img_notch_stretched)

# show results
cv2.imshow("ORIGINAL", img)
cv2.imshow("MAG", mag)
cv2.imshow("PHASE", phase)
cv2.imshow("SPECTRUM", spec)
cv2.imshow("MASK", mask)
cv2.imshow("NOTCH", img_notch)
cv2.imshow("NOTCH_STRETCHED", img_notch_stretched)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Spectrum:

[image]

Mask:

[image]

Notched Filter Result:

[image]

Notched Filter Contrast Enhanced:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a Weiner filter. It won't give you as sharp a result you have shown in the question but it can remove the chessboard noise.

```
from skimage import color, data, restoration
from scipy.signal import convolve2d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('chessboard.jpg', 0)
psf = np.ones((9, 9)) / 81
img = convolve2d(img, psf, 'same')
img += 0.1 * img.std() * np.random.standard_normal(img.shape)
deconvolved_img = restoration.wiener(img, psf, 1, clip=False)

plt.imshow(deconvolved_img, cmap='gray')
```

[image: Result]

If you want to use OpenCV further on this result convert it to `uint8` using `res = deconvolved_img.astype(np.uint8)`